# Is there structured data for a list of latest earthquakes to get a rich snippet in Google?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have a page with a list of latest earthquakes.
Is possible to use `schema.org` structured data to have rich snippet in Google search results showing part of this list?

If so, please provide an example.

Comment: Google's list of rich snippets that are available is here:  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery  I'm not seeing anything on there with a quick glance, but somebody with more experience with rich snippets could give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller do you think is there something for my project ? i want a carousel... but i'm not restaurant :D

Comment: Google says the carousel rich snippet is only for the following types: Recipe, Course, Restaurant, Movie.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller so I rephrase the question differently: I have this page with a map and a list of the latest earthquakes. Each item in the list (one item = one earthquake) contains essential data (of the earthquake) and a link that sends the user to a page with more details. You say I could implement some rich snippets on this page? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Comment: :( ok thanks a lot

Comment: @StephenOstermiller maybe "event" is good for my project ?